# Using ng-option as a filter with unique and null options

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a select filter based upon the objects in an array. One of the issue's I'm having is getting the filter to work with an "All" option with an empty value.

The table initially loads fine with all displayed but when I select a different option then go back to "All" my table is blank.

I've added documentType.MimeType as documentType.MimeType to get a specific field in an object to filter on and was thinking an empty value would be ignored by the filter. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="documentType" id="documentType"
        ng-options="documentType.MimeType as documentType.MimeType for documentType in documentTypes"
        ng-model="selectedDocType">
    <option value="" selected="selected">All Document Types</option>
</select>

<tr ng-repeat="document in documents | filter:selectedDocType">
```

Controller:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedDocType = "";

    $scope.documents = [
        {"FileName": "Test1.pdf", "MimeType": "application/pdf"}
        ,{"FileName": "Test2.pdf", "MimeType": "application/pdf"}
        ,{"FileName": "Cube1.png", "MimeType": "image/png"}
        ,{"FileName": "Cube2.png", "MimeType": "image/png"}
        ,{"FileName": "Cup1.jpg", "MimeType": "image/jpeg"}
        ,{"FileName": "Cup2.jpg", "MimeType": "image/jpeg"}
        ,{"FileName": "Cup3.jpg", "MimeType": "image/jpeg"}
        ]

    $scope.documentTypes = _.uniq($scope.documents, false, function(docType){return docType.MimeType});    
  }
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EaIxCl2FaGwmDkj7t5il

I ended up checking github to see if there are any issues reported around this prior to posting my question and found this:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1780

To fix my issue I made a change to the ng-repeat on the tr element:

```
<tr ng-repeat="document in documents | filter:selectedDocType || '!!'">
```

Fixed Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8z2BNfZaf7rlTsiWvtCw

I posted my question anyways to possibly help the next person.

Comment: Had the same problem. Thanks. 

I commented anyways to tell the next person after me that this solution works.